# Selenium doesn't move to the next element

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I am trying to make a instagrambot with selenium. I am trying to click post or story in the dropdown menu, when inspect(developer tools) is open, they don't work when I first click the create [+] button. In terminal it looks like it just pauses and don't move on to the next element, it doesn't give an error.

But when I click the create [+] button myself and wait for the "post" xpath to click on post, it works and opens the filedialog.

```
<div aria-hidden="false" class="_ad8j _aa5x _aa5-"><div class="_aa61"><div class="_abm4" aria-disabled="false" role="button" tabindex="0" style="cursor: pointer;"><div aria-labelledby="f164fa7b8b81fb f25b63fbbbaab04 fa96d5b7069bd8 f8578df4b0a8" class="_ab8w  _ab94 _ab97 _ab9f _ab9k _ab9p  _ab9- _aba8 _abcm"><div class="_ab8w  _ab94 _ab99 _ab9h _ab9m _ab9o _abcm"><div class="_ab8w  _ab94 _ab99 _ab9f _ab9m _ab9p _abcm" id="f25b63fbbbaab04"><div class="_aacl _aaco _aacu _aacx _aada"><div class="_ab8w  _ab94 _ab99 _ab9h _ab9m _ab9p  _abbi _abcm" style="height: 28px;"><div class="_aacl _aaco _aacu _aacx _aada">Post</div></div></div></div></div><div class="_ab8w  _ab94 _ab99 _ab9f _ab9m _ab9p  _abb1 _abcm"><svg aria-label="Post" class="_ab6-" color="#fafafa" fill="#fafafa" height="16" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="16"><rect fill="none" height="18" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" width="18" x="3" y="3"></rect><line fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" x1="9.015" x2="9.015" y1="3" y2="21"></line><line fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" x1="14.985" x2="14.985" y1="3" y2="21"></line><line fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" x1="21" x2="3" y1="9.015" y2="9.015"></line><line fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" x1="21" x2="3" y1="14.985" y2="14.985"></line></svg></div></div></div><div class="_abm4" aria-disabled="false" role="button" tabindex="0" style="cursor: pointer;"><div aria-labelledby="f4f45cbdcdfb08 f38d9baa8e9f58 f151c2901bc3fe4 ff0e85333e79a8" class="_ab8w  _ab94 _ab97 _ab9f _ab9k _ab9p  _ab9- _aba8 _abcm"><div class="_ab8w  _ab94 _ab99 _ab9h _ab9m _ab9o _abcm"><div class="_ab8w  _ab94 _ab99 _ab9f _ab9m _ab9p _abcm" id="f38d9baa8e9f58"><div class="_aacl _aaco _aacu _aacx _aada"><div class="_ab8w  _ab94 _ab99 _ab9h _ab9m _ab9p  _abbi _abcm" style="height: 28px;"><div class="_aacl _aaco _aacu _aacx _aada">Story</div></div></div></div></div><div class="_ab8w  _ab94 _ab99 _ab9f _ab9m _ab9p  _abb1 _abcm"><svg aria-label="Story" class="_ab6-" color="#fafafa" fill="#fafafa" height="16" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="16"><path d="M3.914 5.32q.338-.406.714-.778m-3.122 7.855a9.903 9.903 0 0 1-.007-.386 10.49 10.49 0 0 1 .517-3.265m3.242 11.337a10.568 10.568 0 0 1-2.89-3.864m14.482 5.109a10.535 10.535 0 0 1-8.162.649M12.001 1.51a10.505 10.505 0 0 1 7.926 17.392" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"></path><line fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" x1="12" x2="12" y1="8.006" y2="16.006"></line><line fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" x1="16" x2="8" y1="12.006" y2="12.006"></line></svg></div></div></div></div><div class="_aa62"></div></div>




from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
chrome_options.add_argument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs")
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/smitty/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome")
chrome_options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 3")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/smitty/Downloads/chromedriver_mac64/chromedriver", options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
driver.refresh()

time.sleep(10)
create = driver.find_element("xpath", '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/section/div[1]/nav/div/header/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a/div')
create.click()
create.click()

#### It works but not when I have the create enabled
time.sleep(5)
Post = driver.find_element("xpath", '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/section/div[1]/nav/div/header/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div')
Post.click()

# time.sleep(10)
# Story = driver.find_element("xpath", '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/section/div[1]/nav/div/header/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div')
# Story.click()

# time.sleep(10)
# driver.quit()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZINmk.png

Comment: When you click on Create does it open a popup? If so you must first close it in order to be able to click other elements outside the popup

Comment: When selenium click the create button it reveals a dropdown menu with post and story, then it is supposed to click on post in the dropdown menu, but it won't do the procedure

Comment: Add to the question the html of the dropdown menu. Is `Post.click()` supposed to click "post" in the dropdown menu?

Comment: Indeed Post.click() is supposed to click "post" in the dropdown menu :)

Comment: ok add the dropdown's html (with children nodes) in the question

Comment: I don't think I understand how to do that? :)

Comment: click edit (look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQmyY.png)) and paste the html code of the dropdown  menu

Comment: I could not figure out how to copy the html right, so I also add a picture to the buttom

Comment: Try this `Post = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[text()="Post"]')` and let me know. To copy the html just open the DevTools, click on an element and press F2, then you can select and copy

Comment: I figured out that it is the create button which stops the code from running the next element, I don't know why. But I have tried waiting for the element, and tried action press hold, perform and release, but when it holds the press on create button, it gets stuck... The same goes for javascript executer

Comment: Did you try the command I suggested you? Moreover, where is the dropdown you are talking about? When I go to the homepage this is what I see https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfqy0.png and if I click on Create it opens this popup https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyeKq.png so I don't see any dropdown menu

Comment: It is because I make it into a simulation of a mobile using developer tools. https://imgur.com/a/qbVnkS4

Comment: Ok I switched to mobile simulation and after few tries I was able to click on "post" button via python, but then it opens a popup to select the file on the computer, so you have to use pyautogui because selenium doesn't work with popups

Comment: So selenium clicked on the [+] button and then on post in the dropdown menu? Can you send code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual `.click()` doesn't work for the [+] button: the script hangs on this command, don't know why, it may be that the driver thinks the page is not loaded yet. Then I tried with javascript and it works:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

create = WebDriverWait(driver,9).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'nav a[role=link]')))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", create)
```

After this click a dropdown menu opens. I tried several methods to click on the "Post" button and finally found one that works:

```
post = WebDriverWait(driver,9).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[text()="Post"]/ancestor::div[@role="button"]')))

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
post.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

## click but hang on
# post.click()

## no click and no hang on
# driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", post)

## no click and hang on
# from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
# actions = ActionChains(driver)
# actions.move_to_element(post).click().perform()

## no click and no hang on
# actions.move_to_element(post).send_keys(Keys.RETURN).perform()

## no click and hang on
# actions.click_and_hold(post).perform()
# time.sleep(1)
# actions.release(post).perform()
```

After this click a popup opens which lets you select the file to upload, however you cannot use selenium to interact with it but you have to use pyautogui.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for you time, I will give it a go as soon as possible. I use Autoit since I am on a windows and it is more reliable, then pyautogui. Also you can write the path into where the name goes in the filedialog and click open.

Comment: And yes the problem was exactly the [+] button got stuck

Comment: @smith How do you do that with Autoit?

Comment: It uses windows id's, so a button has a id, the input has a id, then you just send the path to the id, and it clicks the button. But it only works with windows system. It doesn't work with other programs. So it works with windows file explorer, windows icons etc. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pK478CTLuV4